# ReactJS dynamic function assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and stuck trying assign parent's function to children created dynamically

```
class Row extends React.Component {

handleStateChange() {
    console.log(this); //just for test
}

render() {
    let notes = [],
        categoryId = this.props.rowNo;

    bonuses.forEach(function (bonus, i) {
        let id = 'cell_' + categoryId.toString() + (i + 1).toString();
        notes.push(<NoteCell bonus={bonus}
                             songName={id + '.mp3'}
                             id={id}
                             key={id}
                                        // that is the point
                             handleRowStateChange={this.handleStateChange}
        />);
    });

    return (
        <div className="row clearfix">
            {notes}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I get `Cannot read property 'handleStateChange' of undefined` error.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scope of `this` inside callback function refer to calling object, not to the react class.So Use `()=>` instead of `function`.

```
handleStateChange() {
    console.log(this); //just for test
    this.setState({parentState:value})
}

bonuses.forEach((bonus, i) =>{
    let id = 'cell_' + categoryId.toString() + (i + 1).toString();
    notes.push(<NoteCell bonus={bonus}
                         songName={id + '.mp3'}
                         id={id}
                         key={id}
                                    // that is the point
                         handleRowStateChange={this.handleStateChange.bind(this)}
    />);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suppose this is best practise in all cases?

Comment: Yes @Dimitry. You should.

Comment: By the way `console.log(this)` print child element but i need to change **parent** state. How can i do it?

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, no. `this.setState is not a function`

Comment: handleRowStateChange={this.handleStateChange.bind(this)}  , have you added this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140230/discussion-between-dmitry-and-ved).

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` is refering to the `bonuses.forEach(function` function rather than `this` from your component class. An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) should eliminate that problem.

```
bonuses.forEach((bonus, i) => {
```

As an aside, outside of React if you are not using ES6 then you could do this by getting copy of `this` at the top of your function and then use it inside your function:

```
render() {
    let notes = [],
        categoryId = this.props.rowNo
        self = this;
        ...

        handleRowStateChange={self.handleStateChange}
```

But you still have another problem. When you get inside the `handleStateChange` function, it too will have its own `this`. You can solve that with a constructor:

```
class Row extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind(this);

  }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation!